# StringVar() from JSON list using pop() - Python / tkinter

Tags: python, json, dictionary, tkinter

I am trying to create a basic quiz program using tkinter for Python. Right now I am trying to load a question from a list of two dictionaries from a JSON file:

```
[
{
"wrong3": "Nope, also wrong",
"question": "Example Question 1",
"wrong1": "Incorrect answer",
"wrong2": "Another wrong one",
"answer": "Correct answer"
},
{
"wrong3": "0",
"question": "How many good Matrix movies are there?",
"wrong1": "2",
"wrong2": "3",
"answer": "1"
}
]
```

I'm trying to create a function to pull a dictionary from the list by iterating through the dict via index then using pop() to remove it from the list. I am then trying to use stringVar() to place the question in a label to no avail!

I'm assuming my problem is with the pop() method though I'm not sure how else to go ahead. Should I move on from pop() and try something else?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import json
import random




class ProgramGUI:

    def __init__(self):

        try:
            f = open('question.txt', 'r')
            questions = json.load(f)
            f.close()

        except FileNotFoundError:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Missing/Invalid file')
            command=self.main.destroy
            return


        score = 0


        self.main = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main.title('Quizbox')

        self.mainFrame = tkinter.Frame(self.main, width=350, height=150, bg="green", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.mainFrame.pack(side="top")

        #Question
        self.questionString = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.questionBox = tkinter.Label(self.mainFrame, justify="center", bg="grey",
                                             wraplength=300, pady=10, textvariable=self.questionString)
        self.questionBox.pack(side="top")

        #Frames
        self.frame1 = tkinter.Frame(self.mainFrame, bg="white", pady=5)
        self.frame2 = tkinter.Frame(self.mainFrame, bg="white")
        self.frame1.pack(fill="x")
        self.frame2.pack(fill="x")

        #Buttons (Yet to be completed)
        self.answer1 = tkinter.Button(self.frame1, text="Answer 1")
        self.answer1.pack(side="left")
        self.answer2 = tkinter.Button(self.frame1, text="Answer 2")
        self.answer2.pack(side="left")
        self.answer3 = tkinter.Button(self.frame1, text="Answer 3")
        self.answer3.pack(side="left")
        self.answer4 = tkinter.Button(self.frame1, text="Answer 4")
        self.answer4.pack(side="left")

        buttonList = []
        buttonList.append(self.answer1)
        buttonList.append(self.answer2)
        buttonList.append(self.answer3)
        buttonList.append(self.answer4)


        #Score
        self.scoretext = tkinter.Label(self.frame2, width=20, justify="right", text="Score:" )
        self.scorecount = tkinter.Label(self.frame2, width=20, text="0", bg="white")
        self.scoretext.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.scorecount.pack(side="left")




        self.loadQuestion(questions)
        tkinter.mainloop()




    def loadQuestion(self):
        quest = questions[i]['question']
        self.questionString.set(quest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pop doesn't work like that.

array.pop(n) takes an integer parameter, n, and returns and removes the nth item from a list. If possible it is best to remove only the last item as the avoids re-indexing the list. [Document link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
questions[i]['question']
```

returns the text of the question, not an integer.

But as there is no need to remove questions from the list. Instead

```
def loadQuestion(self,i)
    """Load the ith question and set in in the stringVar
    questionString""""
    quest = questions[i]['question']
    self.questionString.set(quest)
```

You call this method each time you update question.